# Google maps API charset for http request ?? Geocoding Requests

Tags: geocoding, google, api

im sending the following request to maps api but receiving the json response with chars problem. Can some one point me in the right direction to set charset correctly ?
Request -- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.676817,-9.178433&sensor=false
Response of formated_address = R. dos LusÃ­adas, 2805 Almada, Portugal
Where it should be R dos Lusíadas, 2805 Almada, Portugal.

Thanks 
Jorge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query string there is no information about language (i.e., no [language parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)). Besides when loading the Google Maps API Javascript code on client side, you give no information about the language settings. Please, have a look at [Google Maps API localization](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Localization).